# CSS Navbar Align Center

Tags: css, nav

So on my website I'm trying to get my Nav menu to align center but it's not working for some reason. I tried applying

```
margin-right: auto; 
margin-left:auto;
```

I also tried other CSS tricks but it still won't align center. Can someone look at my site with firebug and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

my website is http://dev.pti-world.com
I thought I knew CSS decently well but obviously not since I am having this little problem I can't figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center it you can use `margin: 0 auto;`

There are 2 lines you need to change in your css:

1. You have the width of the ul on 100%.
2. You have the ul with float left.

Solution:

```
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu { 
   float:left;    <---- delete this because with a float you cant center it.
}
```

and change this

```
#megaMenu.megaMenuHorizontal ul.megaMenu {
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap your navi again and give the wrapper

```
text-align:center;
```

and your navi

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `ul` centered text, and make your `li`s not floated and inline-block:

```
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu {
    text-align: center;
}
#megaMenu ul.megaMenu > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

That will work back to Internet Explorer 8.